# Append multiple divs at particular positions in a grid in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading a grid of news stories and want to append two DFP adverts at a particular place in the grid - which is define by a data attribute `data-adposition`

Here's the HTML of the divs

```
<div class="aggregator"> 
  <div class="news-item"> </div>
  <div class="news-item"> </div>
  <div class="news-item"> </div>
  <div class="news-item"> </div>
</div>

<!-- AS AN EXAMPLE I WANT TO APPEND AFTER THE 2ND AND 4TH BUT THIS COULD CHANGE -->

<div class="aggregator__dfp" data-dfpcode='<?php echo $dfpCode; ?>' data-halfcode='<?php echo $dfpHalfCode; ?>'>
    <div class="dfp" data-adposition="<?php echo $dfpPos; ?>">
        <h2>Test DFP ONE</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="dfp" data-adposition="<?php echo $dfpHalfPos; ?>">
        <h2>Test DFP TWO</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am then looping through and currently using `detach()` to preserve the data but remove it from the document.

```
$(".dfp").each(function(){
    var dfpHTML = $(this).detach();
    var dfpPos = $(this).data("adposition");
    $(selector + " .news-item").eq(dfpPos).after(dfpHTML);
});
```

Having no luck currently! The `detach()` works as it stores the data when I `console.log` but does no append to the position defined in the `data-adposition`

Answer (score 0):

it works for me.  what are you getting back from the php expression for data-adposition?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var selector = ".aggregator";
  $(".dfp").each(function(){
    var dfpHTML = $(this).detach();
    var dfpPos = $(this).data("adposition");
    $(selector + " .news-item").eq(dfpPos).after(dfpHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="aggregator"> 
  <div class="news-item">n1 </div>
  <div class="news-item">n2 </div>
  <div class="news-item">n3 </div>
  <div class="news-item">n4 </div>
</div>

<!-- AS AN EXAMPLE I WANT TO APPEND AFTER THE 2ND AND 4TH BUT THIS COULD CHANGE -->

<div class="aggregator__dfp" data-dfpcode='<?php echo $dfpCode; ?>' data-halfcode='<?php echo $dfpHalfCode; ?>'>
    <div class="dfp" data-adposition="1">
        <h2>Test DFP ONE</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="dfp" data-adposition="2">
        <h2>Test DFP TWO</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah that's so weird! I am getting a single number back. The divs `(.news-item)` are dynamically generated - could it not find the grid to append to?

Comment: you might have some race condition happening.  run console.log($(selector + " .news-item")); and see what you get back.